# Replace rows in one dataframe with another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace the values of rows in one dataframe with another.

The following is the sample code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

raceA = ['r1','r3','r4','r5','r6','r7','r8', 'r9']
qualifierA = ['last','first','first','first','last','last','first','first']
participantA = ['rat','rat','cat','cat','rat','dog','dog','dog']
dfA = pd.DataFrame(
    {'race':raceA,
     'qualifier':qualifierA,
     'participant':participantA

    }
)
pprint(dfA)

raceB = ['r1','r2','r3','r4','r5','r6','r7','r8', 'r9','r10']
qualifierB = ['last',np.nan,np.nan,'first','first','last','last','first','first',np.nan]
participantB = ['rat','rat',np.nan,'cat','cat','rat','dog','dog',np.nan,np.nan]
dfB = pd.DataFrame(
    {'race':raceB,
     'qualifier':qualifierB,
     'participant':participantB

    }
)
pprint(dfB)
dfB.loc[dfB.race.isin(dfA.race), ['qualifier','participant']] = dfA[['qualifier','participant']]
pprint(dfB)
```

For instance in dfA,

```
r9     first         dog
```

dfB  contains,

```
 r9     first         NaN
```

Desired output:
dfB

```
r9     first         dog
```

Output obtained:

```
r9       NaN         NaN
```

Could someone look into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with dataframe as:

```
df = dfB.set_index('race').fillna(dfA.set_index('race')).reset_index()

print(df)
  race qualifier participant
0   r1      last         rat
1   r2       NaN         rat
2   r3     first         rat
3   r4     first         cat
4   r5     first         cat
5   r6      last         rat
6   r7      last         dog
7   r8     first         dog
8   r9     first         dog
9  r10       NaN         NaN
```

Or using `update`:

```
dfB = dfB.set_index('race')
dfA = dfA.set_index('race')

dfB.update(dfA)

print(dfB.reset_index())
 race qualifier participant
0   r1      last         rat
1   r2       NaN         rat
2   r3     first         rat
3   r4     first         cat
4   r5     first         cat
5   r6      last         rat
6   r7      last         dog
7   r8     first         dog
8   r9     first         dog
9  r10       NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Just wanted to add a suggestion, can also use `df.update()` instead of `df.fillna()` if the replacement should be unconditional. Also I think the OP is interested in the second code snippet, perhaps it can be brought to the top.

Comment: @crazyGamer added but it is little tricky, since update inplace the original dataframe directly.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this in multiple steps.

First I will merge the two dataframes -

```
dfB_PreProcessing = dfB.merge(dfA,left_on='race',right_on='race',how="left")
```

[image]
Then Clean the participant column -

```
dfB_PreProcessing['participant_x'] = dfB_PreProcessing['participant_x'] .replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
dfB_PreProcessing['participant'] = np.where(dfB_PreProcessing['participant_x'] == '', dfB_PreProcessing['participant_y'], dfB_PreProcessing['participant_x'])
```

Then clean the qualifier column (if needed to) -

```
dfB_PreProcessing['qualifier_x'] = dfB_PreProcessing['qualifier_x'] .replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)
dfB_PreProcessing['qualifier'] = np.where(dfB_PreProcessing['qualifier_x'] == '', dfB_PreProcessing['qualifier_y'], dfB_PreProcessing['qualifier_x'])*
```

Then select only the required columns as output df-

```
dfB = dfB_PreProcessing.loc[:,['race','qualifier','participant']]
```

[image]

Let me know, if it works or it doesn't.

Comment: Consider a left merge instead of inner merge, that is why r2 and r10 are missing in the first table printed.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me If I am not getting It properly.
If you want to update a row of one or multiple columns then you can update the value of that particular index of that column.
eg.
If I want to update all rows in B column then

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B': [4,5,6]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'B':[7,8,9]})
df.update(df1)
pprint(df)
```