# How to replace values in pandas dataframe with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df1) that I want to replace the values in the `symtom_1`, `symptom_2`... with the `weight` values from the df2 dataframe.

The first dataframe has 4000 rows and 17 columns

```
df1

   Disease            Symptom_1    Symptom_2    Symptom_3
0  Fungal infection   itching      itching      NaN
1  Fungal infection   skin_rash    itching      NaN
2  Fungal infection   itching      itching      NaN
3  Fungal infection   itching      itching      skin_rash
4  vertigo            itching      skin_rash    skin_rash
5  vertigo            vomiting     skin_rash    vomiting
6  vertigo            vomiting     skin_rash    vomiting
7  vertigo            vomiting     vomiting     skin_rash
8  Fungal infection   vomiting     vomiting     vomiting
9  Fungal infection   skin_rash    skin_rash    vomiting
10 Fungal infection   skin_rash    vomiting     itching
```

The second dataframe has 133 rows

```
df2

    Symptom              weight
0   itching                 1
1   skin_rash               3
2   nodal_skin_eruptions    4
3   continuous_sneezing     4
4   shivering               5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace rows in one dataframe with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805531/replace-rows-in-one-dataframe-with-another)

Comment: Stack Overflow has wealth of information on how to replace dataframes with another. Please research the link i shared above

Comment: or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63418515/pandas-map-column-values-from-one-df-to-another-based-on-matching-column-values

Comment: I don't think either of those dupes directly answer OP question. merging would first require melting the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `replace` and pass in a dictionary.

```
repl_dict = df2.set_index('Symptom')['weight'].to_dict()

print(df1.replace(repl_dict))

             Disease Symptom_1 Symptom_2 Symptom_3
0   Fungal infection         1         1       NaN
1   Fungal infection         3         1       NaN
2   Fungal infection         1         1       NaN
3   Fungal infection         1         1         3
4            vertigo         1         3         3
5            vertigo  vomiting         3  vomiting
6            vertigo  vomiting         3  vomiting
7            vertigo  vomiting  vomiting         3
8   Fungal infection  vomiting  vomiting  vomiting
9   Fungal infection         3         3  vomiting
10  Fungal infection         3  vomiting         1
```

---

```
repl_dict

{'itching': 1,
 'skin_rash': 3,
 'nodal_skin_eruptions': 4,
 'continuous_sneezing': 4,
 'shivering': 5}
```